# Taking code out of AppDelegate alters view negatively

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS development and trying to implement the Twitter iOS Navigation Bar with Pages.

I came across this: https://github.com/aubrey/SwiftPagingNav/tree/master/SwiftPagingNav

When I loaded this up, it worked great, but I need to get to that UIViewController after the User successfully logs in.

So, I took the code out of AppDelegate and placed it into my own PagingNavController `viewDidLoad()` function. However, when I remove the `window.makeKeyAndBackground()`, the Navigation Bar doesn't show up and when I do include it, I get a unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance error.

Further, I don't know if it is good practice to mess with the Window outside of AppDelegate.

How would I compartmentalize the code into the PagingNavController?

**Edit:**

What I am trying to accomplish is to have 2 pages, which you could navigate through like Twitter does. Both of these pages should have their own ViewControllers that house TableViews.

I successfully managed

to change the second of the 3 scrolling views they show in the link above into one of my ViewControllers:

The code I used was:

```
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewController") as? ViewController
view2 = viewController?.view
view2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.231, green:0.529, blue:0.757, alpha: 1)
view2.frame = CGRectMake(wBounds, 0, wBounds, hBounds)
self.scrollView.addSubview(view2)
self.scrollView.bringSubviewToFront(view2)
```

However, I noticed I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I press a button in my ViewController.

I am guessing using ScrollViews might not be the best way to achieve what I want?

**Update:** I managed to fix my bug I had in the edit above, but I still can't seem to programmatically generate a Navigation Bar. only works from the AppDelegate code, but I don't understand why.

**BIG UPDATE:** I managed to get the functionality to my liking, basically!

In viewDidLoad, I do the following:

```
var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, 64))

// Lots of code from above link. Make sure to delete
// self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(navbarView)

navBar.addSubview(navbarView)
self.view.addSubview(navBar)
```

Then, change viewDidLayoutSubviews to:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        navbarView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 64)
    }
```

Basically, I create my own Navigation Bar and then I position it according to iOS specs.

The only issue I have (for some reason) is that the titles are all clumped together until the user starts scrolling for the first time. This should be an easy fix though.

Comment: Yeah you really can't move the code that is in AppDelegate out. That setup needs to remain in AppDelegate. You might want to explain a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish. Further explanation and code would help.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add your viewController as a "child" view controller of the PagingNavController

Try adding the following lines after the bringSubviewToFront call

```
addChildViewController(viewController!)
viewController?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

See the following line for more info:
http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html

Side node: You should probably make the viewController non-optional. It is currently optional because you use the `as?` but since you are sure that it won't be nil you can use the `as` (without the `?`). Then you can remove the ? and ! after any references to viewController

Comment: Great! That worked! Now I don't get an error when I press the button in my view. My big issue now is how to compartmentalize the stuff in AppDelegate, such that I can segue to this ViewController from my LoginRegisterViewController

Comment: is there any reason why the setup needs to be in the AppDelegate?

Comment: I believe the window's rootViewController needs to be set by the time application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: finishes. I don't know what the relationship between your view controllers is but It sounds like you may want to make LoginRegisterViewController your rootViewController and then once the user logs in then transition to the PagingNavController after that.

Comment: Well, I have LoginRegisterViewController as my initial one via the Storyboard. If the user is already logged in (assume they exited the app and then relaunched), I open up the PagingNavController, otherwise I continue with loading up the LoginRegisterViewController data. Am I supposed to do anything in the application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: Still haven't managed to create the Navigation Bar in the viewDidLoad() function

Comment: I edited the parent to reflect a lot of progress I made, I'm not sure if it is the appropriate way to solve this though.